# Diagonal lines from bicubic downsample

Tags: photoshop-cs5

I'm trying to convert some photographs of oil paintings to the best images possible for a computer screen slide show.The images were shot at 300dpi and go from 2500px across to 3500px.

When I do the PhotoShop image | image size with a bicubic (smooth gradients)  down sample I get the best results if I just change the resolution from 300 to 72 and leave the width alone. That gives me a picture of around 800px across (3000 * 72 /300 - 720) which is ok. But if I try to force the width up to 800 the result has diagonal ridges in the canvas that look like some kind of "beat frequency" occurring during the downsample.

Does anyone understand what's going on here? What's the best practice for downsampling?

Thanks

Comment: your question are off topic, why waste hard-earned 50 rep?

Comment: Are you trying to upsample after downsampling? Or are you getting the lines from the initial downsample? One thing to try would be to do multiple smaller downsamples. I've heard of people getting better image quality going this route for both down and upsampling.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to upsample. The initial downsample creates the lines.  I'm starting with a - let's say - 2500  x 2000 image shot at 300dpi and I want to convert it to something around 800 x 640 with the best possible quality. But I get these stripes if I force the width to 800 in the downsample step.  I do better if I just set the down sampled resolution to 72dpi, which gives me an image about  800px across but is free of the artifacts. I'm looking for an explanation of what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do a proper down sampling, you need to blur the image first. The blurring will get rid of the high frequency signal in the image so you won't get artifact. The kernel size for blurring depends on how much you want to down-sample. If you are downsampling by a factor of 2, a 2x2 kernel should do.

Comment: That sounds like excellent and unexpected advice.  Could you possibly point me to some kind of reference where this is talked about more?